# Debugging kernel boot flow before start_kernel on ARM

Tags: android, linux-kernel, arm, boot, bootloader

What are the different ways to debug boot flow before start_kernel() is called? I am referring to the code present in **head.S and related assembly files**. Debugging techniques using the ***serial port*** would be helpful since Trace32 is not available. :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any LEDs on your target system? I used LED to help me trace where the boot flow went and hung. Maybe you can try and it's quite simple by controlling GPIOs.

Comment: +1, Did that myself too, however it can turn quite ugly and difficult as register pressure increases in certain hand written assembly functions inside the kernel itself unless the stack is setup where you can just push/pull from it.